# Google Calendar API returns a 404 when trying to get all my calendar events

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to log all my events to the console. Should be fairly simple, but it can't find my calendar for some reason (the id is definitely correct, and my API key isn't blank in my actual code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Calendar Example</title>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
    <script>
        var apiKey = '';

        function load()
        {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function()
                {
                    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                        'calendarId': 'timtamboy63@gmail.com'
                    });

                    request.execute(function(resp)
                    {
                        console.log(resp);
                    });
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

The response:

```
Object {code: 404, message: "Not Found", data: Array[1], error: Object}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your calendar ID is incorrect. It should look something like gma9l2if4e75ta6cr7ubndts@group.calendar.google.com

Comment: How would I find the calendar ID?

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list to get a list of your calendars, including their ID

Comment: Looks like the id is definitely correct - http://cl.ly/image/2b08202m0I3M. Any ideas?

Comment: try listing the events using the https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it and then compare the HTTP request with what your app is sending